# PHP - If a string or variable begins with a vowel

Tags: php, if-statement

I did a if thing to check if the variable only had aplha caracter but I also want to check if the variable strated with a vowel.

```
if (ctype_alpha($original)) {
        print "oké";
    }
    else {
        print "pas oké";
    }
```

If there isn't any specific function, how could I know ?
Thank you

Comment: `if (in_array($original{0}, ['a','e','i','o','u'])) { // begins with a vowel }`

Comment: Thank you @Mark Baker. Your answer works better for me that `ctype_alpha()` because my variable also contains string with space in between.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$vocals = array('a','e','i','o','u');

if (ctype_alpha($original) && in_array($original{0}, $vocals)) {
  print "oké";
} else {
  print "pas oké";
}
```

With `$string{index}` you could access to a char into a certain position into `$string`.

With `in_array` you could check if that letter is contained into an array (in our example, vocals array)

---

#### Alternative solution

If you wish, you could even use `preg_match` that will perform test with regular expressions

```
if (ctype_alpha($original) && preg_match('/^[aeiou]/i', $original))
```

Answer (score 0):

Working as of PHP 7.4:

```
$vowels = array('a','e','i','o','u');

if (ctype_alpha($original) && in_array($original[0], $vowels)) {
  print "oké";
} else {
  print "pas oké";
}
```